# failed to @extend ".class". The selector ".class" was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, scss

**Application.css**

```
*= require palette
*= require global
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

**vendor/assets/stylesheet/pallete.scss**

```
.grey {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

**global.scss**

```
html {
  body {
    header {
      @extend .grey;
    }
  }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> "html body header" failed to @extend ".grey".
>   The selector ".grey" was not found.
>   Use "@extend .grey !optional" if the extend should be able
>   to fail.

Если класс `.grey` прописать в файле `global.scss` и в том же файле экстендить - то всё работает нормально, из любых других файлов не экстендит.

Пробовал перемещать файл `palette` из `vendor` в `app`, менять местами порядок в `application.css`, убирал `*= require_tree .`, обновлял гемы, перегружал сервер, компьютер - результат тот же.

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

Тоже ничего не изменили.

В пустом приложении с нуля такая же проблема.

Версии руби и гемов:

- ruby 2.2.0p0
- Rails 4.2.5
- sass (3.4.21)
- sass-rails (5.0.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно, SCSS-файлы компилируются **Sass**'ом поодиночке, а потом **Sprockets** (система сборки ассетов в Rails) сшивает из них итоговые стили (используя директивы `require` в комментариях).

Таким образом, когда собирается `global.scss`, о содержимом `palette.scss` Sass ничего не знает. Чтобы узнал, нужно соответствующий файл [**импортировать**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import):

```
@import 'palette.scss'
```

...да, это очень похоже на CSS-овый `@import`, Sass его синтаксически расширяет, аккуратно отлавливая случаи, когда его нужно оставить "как есть". Фактически это включает содержимое указанного файла на место этой директивы. То есть, импорт можно делать даже внутри блока правил, и всё будет загружено внутрь него. В гайде по ссылке выше расписаны детали.

---

Обращаю внимание, что идиоматичный Sass-импорт обычно происходит с файлами, имеющими `_` в начале имени файла (т. н. *partial*), вроде `_palette.scss`, а импортируют так:

```
@import 'palette'
```

---

Нужно также понимать, что употребление во включаемых файлах кода, который рендерится в непустой CSS, приведёт к тому, что в результате эти блоки будут встречаться несколько раз, если в результате этот файл импортирован несколько раз. Чтобы этого избежать, можно использовать [селектор-заглушку](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_):

```
%grey {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

Если отрендерить эту конструкцию в CSS, получится пустой файл. Но при этом можно делать `@extend %grey`, получая желаемый эффект.

Comment: Спасибо, с Sass и Sprockets всё понятно, но как быть с импортом?
В каждый файл .scss вставлять @import 'palette'? Это как-то не DRY и не вызовет ли это повторение кода из файла palette?

Или же вместо application.css использовать application.scss и там импортировать все .scss файлы?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. )

Comment: @Ampersand это настолько же не DRY, насколько вынесение общего кода в  отдельную функцию не DRY. Да, код из `palette` таким образом будет выведен несколько раз, поэтому есть смысл воспользоваться `%псевдоселекторами`, которые сами по себе не рендерятся, но могут быть использованы для расширения других.

Comment: Эм, я чуть с термином ошибся: это "placeholder selector", селектор-заглушка ([источник](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_)).

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за расширенный ответ!